Capitalise entries in glossaries-extra
I'm using the Latex glossaries-extra package and outputting my glossary using printnoidxglossary. The names of the glossary entries are all lower case, because that's how I want them to appear when I reference them with \gls but in my actual listing of the glossary entries I want at least the first letter capitalised. How can I do that?

Please provide the Minimal Working Example

Irrelevant to the question.
